# Cant get chart.js to work with Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am using VS2017 with Angular 2 spa template

I have followed the following steps

> npm install chart.js --save

I have then configured my component as follows

```
import { ViewChild, Component, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    @ViewChild('chart1') chart1: ElementRef;

    constructor(
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {

        let chart1Ctx = this.chart1.nativeElement.getContext('2d');

        var myChart = new Chart(chart1Ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: ['M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S', 'S'],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'apples',
                    data: [12, 19, 3, 17, 6, 3, 7],
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(153,255,51,0.4)"
                }, {
                    label: 'oranges',
                    data: [2, 29, 5, 5, 2, 3, 10],
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,153,0,0.4)"
                }]
            }
        });        
    }
}
```

When I try and run the component I get

> Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: Uncaught (in
>   promise): TypeError: this.chart1.nativeElement.getContext is not a
>   function

From what I can see it is not able to reference the chart.js function...  Not sure where I need to reference the js file other than what I have tried.

package.json has an entry

```
  "dependencies": {
    ...,
    "chart.js": "^2.6.0",
```

I have added an entry to the webpack.config.vendor.js

```
entry: {
            vendor: [
                ...
                'chart.js',
```

Lastly I tried adding a reference to

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

on the index page.

Comment: Does https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/ not suit your purpose?

Comment: I found that it has the same issue - as it relies on chart.js I believe